# Solving recurrences with an asymptotic formula instead of a starting value.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Suppose for some function R(x) we have a sequence defined by a recurrence relation:
$$a_n = R(a_{n-1})$$

Suppose $a_n$ blows up. Also suppose we don’t know any value of the sequence in advance.  However we do know an asymptotic formula for $a_n$.  **Is this enough information to solve for $a_n$** assuming $a_n$ has only one solution allowed by the asymptotic formula?

I am interested because we could use this to solve certain nested radicals (and probably other nested structures).

Comment: The initial values (or any value in the sequence) can affect the asymptotic behavior based on whether or not it is a fixed point of $R$ (or in general, a fixed point of any $R^k$).

Comment: You state "Suppose $a_n$ blows up" and I assume to you mean that $|a_n|\to\infty$ or equivalently $1/a_n\to 0$. In that case $b_n:=1/a_n$ satisfies $b_n=1/R(1/b_{n-1})$. So there is an equivalent question for $b_n$. Another way of stating this is that infinity is a fixed point of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases $a_n$ will go to a fixed point of $R$, or will blow up.

When there are multiple fixed points, the initial value decides which fixed point it goes to.

For eg if $R(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$, the fixed point is $\phi \approx 1.6$ and this will converge to 1.6 for all $x>-1$. (Why?)